# How to transfer a zipped folder from a desktop to unix server without using winscp/any tools?

Tags: shell, unix, ssh, ftp, sftp

I'm a newbie to unix. My requirement is to create an automation script which will transfer a zipped folder from my/remote desktop to an unix server. Tools lik WinSCP shouldnt be used. No manual moving. I use putty to connect to server. I couldnt find any help on this topic. Should i use ftp commands? If yes, how? What is the basic requirement(security n access-wise) for this transfer to happen? Pls help.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are to use ssh to connect to the Unix/Linux server you could:

1. Use Cygwin on the remote desktop system to have a Linux like shell on the Windows server.
2. Write script using scp(a Linux command to copy files over ssh connection) to copy files over.
3. Then schedule this as a task.

Good luck with all that.